# SEO pros and cons of choosing a long title for my website

Tags: seo, keywords

I've got a company website which offers website design services. I've just started to improve search engine visibility of the website. I've chosen some keywords and the first thing I need to think about is the title of my website. There are 6 important keywords for us. By including all keywords in the title of the website which is something like **company name | keywords**.

I noticed that the title is long and not much readable for the readers on the browser tab.

What are the pros and cons of choosing this long title for my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [nice summary on SEOMoz](http://www.seomoz.org/learn-seo/title-tag).

If your title gets to long the search engine will cut it for you. Title mainly for users, not for the search engine. Spread the keywords over the pages with the specific keyword content.

Forget the "keywords" meta tag (search engines ignore them for a long time) and focus on the "description" tag, as this is what will usually be displayed in the search result.